# 3rd party assembly is looking for a specific version of log4net- how do I resolve this?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I am trialing a cloud based logging system whereby I have to setup an appender for log4net in my `App.config` file.
It is working fine when I run it on my development PC, however when I run it on my server, I get this:

```
log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [LeAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.LogentriesAppender, LogentriesLog4net]. Reported error follows.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(XmlElement appenderElement)
```

I have `log4net 2.0.8.0` however it looks like this assembly is specifically referencing version `1.2.13.0` (confirmed with dotPeek).

I've never using binding redirects but I'm fairly certain this would help in this case. However, why does it work on my local machine? Is this because my local machine has a copy of that version somewhere (such as in the GAC or somewhere else?).

Also.. the documentation for `logentries` has nothing related to having to use a specific version of `log4net`.. surely they would have had this issue crop up before?